# How to dynamic aggregation function (Min, Max, Sum) on generic list using C#?

Tags: c#

Here I am trying to perform different aggregation functions like `Min, Max, Sum` from `IEnumerable` on the generic list (`Transaction->Value`). Here is the code:

```
List<string> funcs = new List<string> { "Min", "Max", "Sum" };
List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction> { new Transaction { Value = 10 }, new Transaction { Value = 20 } };

foreach(string function in funcs)
{
    // transactions.Sum(item => item.Value);
    var func = BuildFunc<Transaction>(nameof(Transaction.Value), function);
    double result = func(transactions);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

Console.ReadKey();

Func<IEnumerable<T>, double> BuildFunc<T>(string propertyName, string func) //Count, Last, First
{
    var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<T>), "source");
    var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
    Expression value = Expression.PropertyOrField(item, propertyName);

    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double>>(value, item);
    var methodCall = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<T>, double>>(
        Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), func, new Type[] { item.Type, selector.ReturnType }, source, selector),
        source);

    return methodCall.Compile();
}

internal class Transaction
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

This code is working for functions `Min` and `Max`, but somehow for `Sum` throwing an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No generic method 'Sum' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments.

These functions are just extensions provided on `IEnumerable`. I am not sure what went wrong here. Any help would be apricated.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar This is sample code from actual problem. We are doing some dynamic filtering and grouping on data filter or grouping could be anything.

Comment: You are trying to create an expression `Enumerable.Sum<Transaction, double>(source, selector)`. Wouldn't the correct call be `Enumerable.Sum<Transaction, Func<Transaction, double>>(source, selector)`?

Comment: @KlausGütter yes found the error in code `selector.ReturnType` in Type need to removed